# Clear recent file list in AppleScript?

Tags: macos, applescript, copy-paste, defaults

I created an AppleScript for cleaning the clipboard which had this command:

```
tell application "System Events" to set the clipboard to ""
```

How would I create an AppleScript that did this with this shell script in Catalina latest version?

I tried:

```
do shell script "defaults delete -g NSNavRecentPlaces"
```

and got this error message:

```
error "2020-06-27 22:20:11.304 defaults[1830:54087] 
Domain (kCFPreferencesAnyApplication) not found.
Defaults have not been changed." number 1
```

How would I get an AppleScript to work for this sort of thing like the clipboard one I made?

Any advice appreciated on this!

Answer (score 1):

In **AppleScript**, you do not need **System Events** to *clear the clipboard*, just use:

```
set the clipboard to ""
```

To use the above **AppleScript** *command* from **Terminal**, use the following command:

```
osascript -e 'set the clipboard to ""'
```

To clear the *general clipboard* from **Terminal**, not using **AppleScript**, use the following command:

```
pbcopy < /dev/null
```

To clear the *find clipboard* from **Terminal**, not using **AppleScript**, use the following command:

```
pbcopy -pboard find < /dev/null
```

---

That all said, there is a discrepancy between the *title* of your *question* and the **AppleScript** *code* you're wanting to run in **Terminal**.

If you are wanting to clear the **Recent Items** on the **Apple** *menu*, then the following **AppleScript** *command* will do that:

```
tell application "System Events" to ¬
    click menu item "Clear Menu" of ¬
        menu 1 of ¬
        menu item "Recent Items" of ¬
        menu 1 of ¬
        menu bar item "Apple" of ¬
        menu bar 1 of ¬
        application process "Finder"
```

To use that in **Terminal**:

```
osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to click menu item "Clear Menu" of menu 1 of menu item "Recent Items" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Apple" of menu bar 1 of process "Finder"'
```